# Applying Knockout binding to a specific part of the page: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, knockout.js

### The Code

- You can find the JSFiddle in question at: http://jsfiddle.net/SeanKilleen/A3QtJ/

### Background / What I'm Trying to Accomplish

- I'd like a Feedback button to place on our web site, likely in the Site.Master file (it's an asp.net web site)
- When the feedback link is clicked, I'd like to show a modal dialog
- I'd like to bind the link and the elements inside of the modal to a specific knockout viewmodel
- I'd like to properly namespace it so that it doesn't interfere with any other scripts that might come up on other pages
- I'd like to apply the Knockout bindings only to this portion of the code, because other subsequent pages, etc. might also have bindings.

To do this, I have the following main toolset: Knockout, jQuery, and jQueryUI (jQueryUI isn't my particular choice but that ship has sailed).

### The Problem

In the [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/SeanKilleen/A3QtJ/), the following code currently works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    vm = new FeedbackNamespace.ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

However, when I change `ko.applyBindings(vm)` to:

```
      ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById('FeedbackArea'));
```

The link part of the binding (that is mound to a viewmodel function to show the dialog) still works. However, none of the bindings *inside* the modal dialog still work.

### Question(s)

- How can I properly apply the viewModel to only a section of the site in this case?
- Is this method of doing things still going to cause problems with child pages that might load their own knockout viewmodels and apply them?
- Are there other examples of this sort of thing being done? I've been looking but unable to find them.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
self.Start();
```

this sets up the modal, removing it from the `FeedbackArea` div.  This happens in the process of *creating* the viewmodel, such that when this newly created vm is actually applied to the div a moment later, that modal is now gone, which is why nothing inside of it responds like it does when you apply the VM to the entire page.

I would make sure that Start method is called AFTER you apply bindings.

[**LIKE THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/A3QtJ/19/)

Comment: Ahhh, makes perfect sense! Thanks; I missed that one bigtime. Appreciate the edit to the JSFiddle as well.